# Using Component in a parent component

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm fairly new to Reactjs. I was just wondering if it's ideal or part of Good or OK practice to have a Parent (Class component) call another Child (Class component). What I'm trying to say is something like this.

Below are the common usage I can see online

```
export default class Login extends Component {
     render() {
        return (
            <LoginForm />
        );
     }
}
```

Then it's going to call a functional component

```
const Form = (props) => {

    return (
       <div>This is the child form</div>
    )
};
```

But I was wondering if it was ok or what are the pro's and con's if a parent class component calls another class component? So in this case the child will be something like this

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {
     render() {
        return (
            <div>This is the child form</div>
        );
     }
}
```

Comment: you can render many child components in parent component.

Comment: if you use functional component you can implement react hooks feature :D

Comment: @AnhTuan so basically it's ok to use Class Component from a Parent Class Component? It won't have any effect of disadvantage?

Comment: @MadzQuestioning its ok React support both Class Component and function component
. what you can do with class component  ,  func component can do the same

Answer (score 0):

If a component is a stateless component, then it is wise to use a functional component. Usually the Parent component which handle major state is a class component and the child component which are stateless or handle very less state is a functional component. You can use react-hooks in the functional component but not in the class component. Moreover functional component are plain javascript functions without state and lifecycle methods. It is much more easier to read and test the functional component and also it might boost up your performance as Class component are heavier than functional component. So the basic idea is if you feel that the component is stateless or handle a very less state then it's better to use functional component rather than using class component. Also you can use anything as your child component, not necessarily you have to use Functional component. **But if the component is stateless, it's a good call to use Functional Component**.